# Apache2 vhost works with www, but not without

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, wordpress, virtualhost

Ok so my site works with the www. but not without. If I visit the page without the www. , I get a 404 message

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at mintuz.com Port 80

my apache 2 access log

```
::1 - - [03/Nov/2012:11:36:51 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
X.X.X.X - - [03/Nov/2012:11:37:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 496 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
X.X.X.X - - [03/Nov/2012:11:37:01 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

my apache 2 error log

> [Sat Nov 03 21:05:06 2012] [error] [client 94.15.36.37] File does not
>   exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs [Sat Nov 03 21:05:06 2012] [error] [client
>   94.15.36.37] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs

My vhost config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mintuz.com
        ServerName www.mintuz.com
        ServerAlias mintuz.com *.mintuz.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I feel as if it's not my DNS because it is hitting my server in both instances, just my server replies with a 404. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Try this, ServerName mintuz.com
ServerAlias *.mintuz.com

Comment: You quote the access_log but not the error_log, which may have interesting tips. Also, are you sure the <VirtualHost> you quote is the only one? Another one may be elsewhere in the large Apache config files, and take precedence.

Comment: I have included my error log

Answer (score 0):

Adding my ip address to the  fixed my issue as well as uncommenting some stuff in the default vhost file.

Comment: Really, "uncommenting some stuff?"  How useful do you think that's going to be to anyone else?